# Knockout typescript extenders

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

Could anyone please post an example of extending an observable in knockout in typescript?
Knockout extender: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html

I am using this version of knockout.d.ts from march 6. 2013
https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/knockout

EDIT: 
Thank you very much! So to extend you 'just' need to add the interface KnockoutExtenders so that typescript will 'allow' it. Example

```
interface KnockoutExtenders {
    logChange(target: any, option: string): KnockoutObservableAny;
}

ko.extenders.logChange = function (target, option) {
    target.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    console.log(option + ": " + newValue);
    });
return target;
};
```

Inside the viewmodel declare like this:

```
this.score = ko.observable(score).extend({ logChange: "score" });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interfaces in typescript are open ended so you can add to them in multiple places.

For example of numeric. You need to app this member to extenders as well as your observables. Here is the example:

```
interface KnockoutExtenders {
    numeric(target: any, precision: number): KnockoutObservableAny;
}
interface KnockoutObservableNumber {
    extend(data: any): KnockoutObservableNumber;
}
ko.extenders.numeric = function (target: KnockoutObservableNumber, digits) {
    var result = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            var value = target();
            var toret: string = value.toString();
            if (toret.length < digits) {
                toret = "0" + toret;
            }
            else if (toret.length > digits) {
                toret = toret.substring(0, digits);
            }
            return toret;
        },
        write: target
    });

    result(target());
    return result;
};
```

You can see a complete sample here : https://github.com/basarat/ChessClock/blob/d82a565ac9720cce00c75f099fcf7003f496755a/ChessClock/ChessClock/www/main.ts

Comment: I assume `KnockoutObservableAny` should now be `KnockoutObservable<any>` with newer typescript / Knockout that supports generics

Comment: and `KnockoutObservableNumber` interface extension here is no longer required (assuming you're using a .d.ts file) - and that `target` should be `KnockoutObservable<number>`

Answer (score 1):

Update based on comment: In that case you just need to extend the interface separately to the definition file:

```
interface KnockoutExtenders {
    logChange: (target: KnockoutObservableAny, option: string) => KnockoutObservableAny;
}
```

Comment: logchange is just an example of a way to extend in that particular example. Further down the page they show how to make 'required' and 'numeric'. We should be able to make those extenders in Typescript but I don't know how..

Comment: @RuneJeppesen - I see - I assumed they were part of the standard library. Answer updated.

Comment: With the tweak to `interface KnockoutExtenders {
    logChange: (target: KnockoutObservable<any>, option: string) => KnockoutObservable<any>;
}`, I still get an error that logChange does not exist on type Knockout Extenders (added interface to a type file that I reference at the top of my extensions.ts). Is there another way to do this with the latest TS?