# How should I add a typescript definition for a knockout extender which adds methods to an observable?

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, observable

I have a knockout extender which I want to use in a typescript file, and I can't work out how to declare it.

The extender is written in javascript, and I want to use it from a typescript file (as the project is currently a mix of javascript and typescript). However, I haven't been able to work out how to add a definition for the extender. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357750/knockout-typescript-extenders) I have added to the `KnockoutExtenders` interface (though I'm not sure if I've missed the point of that question) like so:

```
interface KnockoutExtenders {
    trackChange<T>(target: T, track: boolean): ITrackChange<T>;
}

interface ITrackChange<T> extends KnockoutObservable<T> {
    setOriginalValue(startingValue: T): void;
    resetToConfirmedValue(): void;
    setConfirmedValue(): void;
    numberChanges(): number;
}
```

The usage for the extender is as follows:

```
class ProductTypeViewModel {
    constructor() {
        this.name.setOriginalValue('Initial value');
    }

    name = ko.observable('').extend({
        trackChange: true
    });
}
```

I get a typescript build error on `this.name.setOriginalValue` because `Property 'setOriginalValue' does not exist on type 'KnockoutObservable<string>'`, which is of course true.

How should I declare the extender so that typescript can recognise that the observable has been given new methods (i.e. it is no longer a `KnockoutObservable<string>` and is now an `ITrackChange<string>`)?

(Not sure if an explanation of the extender is relevant, but here it is anyway:
The extender tracks changes to an observable and allows them to be accepted/cancelled. This allows an observable to be used to display a current value, and on an edit modal the same observable can be used to change the value, but the underlying value doesn't actually change until the user confirms their changes in the modal. If they cancel them, nothing is actually changed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to get around the typescript errors by manually casting the type of the observable.

```
name = ko.observable('').extend({
    trackChange: true
}) as ITrackChange<string>;
```

I would prefer to be able to register it somewhere so that I don't have to use this cast on every observable I extend, but doing it manually will suffice. If anyone comes up with a better solution I'll happily accept their answer. (If this is a poor approach please do comment to explain why, I'm always happy to learn!)

Note that if the observable has multiple extenders, an intersection type can be used to show all relevant interfaces, as per [this answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37668981/4051181):

```
name = ko.observable(false).extend({
    trackChange: true,
    logChange: true
}) as ITrackChange<boolean> & ILogChange<boolean>;
```

Comment: You could also get around it by accessing the property via indexer, like "this.name["setOriginalValue"]('Initial value')"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this didn't work for me. `this.name['setOriginalValue']` has a return type of `KnockoutBindingHandler` and trying to call it as a function gives the error `Value of type 'KnockoutBindingHandler' is not callable`. I also get the error `Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.` (TS2349)

Comment: @Tim  i need to implement required extender in type script shown here http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html . im new to typescript could you give suggestions??

Comment: @SrinivasRa If you're new to typescript I'd suggest working through a quick typescript tutorial first to get the hang of the language, then come back to your knockout extenders. 

These comments aren't the ideal place to get help because not many people will see them, and they're really for comments related to this answer, but if you get stuck then you can always ask a new question to get help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
interface KnockoutObservable<T> extends Observable<T> {
  setOriginalValue(param: string): void;
}

class ProductTypeViewModel {
    private name: KnockoutObservable<string>;

    constructor() {
        this.name.setOriginalValue('Initial value');
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it would tell the typescript compiler that all observables have the `setOriginalValue` method on them, which isn't actually the case. The method is only added if the observable is extended with `.extend({ trackChange: true })`.

Comment: I'm not sure if that can be accomplished at compile time. I would consider moving that logic into the method instead.