# Setting Up a Knockout Extender with Typescript (2018)

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am attempting to follow the example laid out here: [Knockout typescript extenders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357750/knockout-typescript-extenders)

In each of these files I actually have a custom `KnockoutBindingHandler` as well that works, so I thought that putting along side the binding handler would be appropriate and work but no such luck.

I have a `customKoBindings.d.ts`

```
import * as ko from "knockout"

interface KnockoutExtenders {
    logChange: (target: KnockoutObservable<any>) => KnockoutObservable<any>;
}
```

---

`extensions.ts`

```
/// <reference path="./customKoBindings.d.ts" />

import * as ko from "knockout"   

export class KnockoutExtensions {
    constructor() {
ko.extenders.logChange = function (target) {
            target.subscribe(function (newValue) {
                console.log(newValue);
            });
            return target;
        };
    }
}
```

`Error  TS2339  (TS) Property 'logChange' does not exist on type 'KnockoutExtenders'.`

I saw [someone](http://www.timlabonne.com/2013/02/building-a-knockout-js-extender-for-boolean-values/) reference their new extender like this: `ko.extenders["logChange"]`

but even still I cannot do this:

```
this.end = ko.observable(end).extend({logChange});
```

`Cannot find name "logChange"`

Is there a new syntax to do this or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript files can be either "ambient" or "modules" — modules are anything that use `import` or `export` — and the way you have to do declaration merging is dependent on which type of file it is.

To merge declarations in a module, you have to use the `declare` keyword. So, you've actually got 2 ways to fix this...

1) Remove `import * as ko from "knockout"` from your declaration file so that it is parsed as ambient.

2) Add `declare` before `interface` in your declaration file.

Answer (score -1):

You could use jquery extend() function to do the same thing (assuming you have imported jquery as 'jquery')

```
jquery.extend(ko.extenders,
{
    logChange: function (target) {
        target.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            console.log(newValue);
        });
        return target;
    }
});
```